# Encode from WAV to AAC and to decode from AAC to WAV using SharpDX

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I want to encode an audio stream, which is in the WAV format, to the AAC format and also decode an AAC audio stream to WAV. Can I implement this with SharpDX's `MediaFoundation` DLL? Then how can I use that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I decode can be done with AudioDecoder class, 
download @ github SharpDx and once on your desktop you will find example in

...\Desktop\SharpDX-master\SharpDX-master\Samples\MediaFoundation\DecodeAudioToWav\

I hope this helpfull

Comment: Decode From a file is possible with the above sample..But i need to encode and decode audio stream.How is that possible?

Comment: infact I wrote "decoding" not encoding I think that half of your problem is now solved, although I think that encoding mp3 into directx is quite impossible, by the way I'm not sure, give a look into msdn magazine online at Perzold Articles.

Comment: Since there is a solution using MFC to encode media with TranscodingProfile class there might be a solution to implement that technique in c#.